# Why set/get_default_resource use pointer and not reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++17

When using C++17 polymorphic allocator and set/get_default_resource methods (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/set_default_resource for instance), all resources are passed/returned by pointer while it makes little to no sens to use nullptr and it feels it could most of the time be a reference (then stored as ref_wrapper if needed).

Is there any logical/style reason for that ?

Comment: I guess it's easier to handle memory the same way `new` does; this is, returning a pointer to the allocated block of memory.

Comment: that's not the point. I'm not talking about allocation/deallocation of memory resource but about the way memory resources as passed around.

the reason memory_resource returns a pointer when allocating isn't because it's easier to do the same way new is doing but because allocation could fail (ex: by lack of memory) therefor returning nullptr is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the page you link cites, `set_default_resource()` does accept a null pointer and has specific behavior for that case:

> If `r` is not null, sets the default memory resource pointer to `r`; otherwise, sets the default memory resource pointer to `std::pmr::new_delete_resource()`.

The initial paper, [N3525](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3525.pdf), also cites as rationale:

> We have found it is convenient to use `nullptr` as a surrogate for the “default-default” handler in various interfaces. The use here simply provides consistency and makes it easy to reset the default resource to its initial state.

And a subsequent revision, [N3916](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3916.pdf), states:

> Note that the memory-resource library is designed so that the `ShoppingList`
>   constructor accepts a pointer to a `memory_resource` rather than a reference to a
>   `memory_resource`. It was noted that one common practice is to use references
>   rather than pointers in situations where a null pointer is out of contract. However, there is a more compelling practice of avoiding constructors that take objects by reference and store their addresses. We also want to avoid passing non-const references, as that, too, is usually considered bad practice (except in overloaded operators).

Comment: About first point it's a good explanation.

About second one I still don't understand why get/set return a pointer and not a reference, and why polymorphic_allocator does take a pointer and not a reference.

Comment: do you have any knowledge about "passing non-const references [...] is usually considered bad practice (except in overloaded operators)" ?
Same for "there is a more compelling practice of avoiding constructors that take objects by reference and store their addresses" : what is the reason behind that ?